# Cakehp 2.3.9 hasMany different table name

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm at a loss here the situation is as follows i have 2 tables:
filter and widget (yes none cake table names which im not allowed to change)

Now filter belongs to widget and widget has many filters both models show up in pr() like this.

```
[name] => Filter
[useTable] => filter
[belongsTo] => Array
    (
        [Widget] => Array
            (
                [className] => Widget
                [foreignKey] => id
                [conditions] => 
                [fields] => 
                [order] => 
                [counterCache] => 
            )

    )
```

and filter

```
[name] => Widget
[useTable] => widget
[hasMany] => Array
    (
        [Filter] => Array
            (
                [className] => Filter
                [foreignKey] => widget
                [conditions] => 
                [fields] => 
                [order] => 
                [limit] => 
                [offset] => 
                [dependent] => 
                [exclusive] => 
                [finderQuery] => 
                [counterQuery] => 
            )

    )
```

Now the problem is as follows when i do a simple:

```
pr($this->Filter->findById(1934));
or
pr($this->Widget->findById(1663));
```

I get an error:

> Missing Database Table
>   Error: Table analyse_widgets for model Widget was not found in datasource default.

But when i use this code it works fine, but this is just to ugly to use evrytime i want to find something:

```
$this->Widget;
pr($this->Filter->findById(1934));
pr($this->Widget->findById(1663));
```

I have no idea how to get this working like it should be. Is it because of the none caketable names ? or is it something i forgot ?

This is what im loading the models with and clearing model cache had no influence:

```
App::uses('Analyse.Filter', 'Model');
App::uses('Analyse.Widget', 'Model');

$this->uses = array('Analyse.Widget', 'Analyse.Filter');
```

Any insight in the situation would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
App::uses('Filter', 'Model');
App::uses('Widget', 'Model');

$this->uses = array('Widget', 'Filter');
```

Add $useTable in your model ie.

```
public $useTable = 'widget'; 
public $useTable = 'filter';
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: The usetable is already defined as you can see in the model array output.

Comment: Yes im also using App::uses for both of them otherwise useTable wont work.

Comment: But you are using App::uses('Analyse.Filter', 'Model');
App::uses('Analyse.Widget', 'Model'); instead of App::uses('Filter', 'Model');
App::uses('Widget', 'Model');

Comment: Yeah was loading from a plugin but already tried without and also tried it in a blank cakephp version in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Seem's when you use a hasMany or belongsTo with custom tablenames cake still makes it's own models to rely on. Unless you recast them again just before a find function which happend whith: $this->Filter and $this->Widget

I made a workaround by putting this in the beforeFilter but its only needed when you use a relation with none cake table names.

```
$this->Filter->useTable = 'filter';
$this->Widget->useTable = 'widget';
```

Comment: check this: [http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses) maybe help you